# Выбор языка программирования для сёрфинга

Tags: javascript, python, php, браузер

Хочу создать сайт/приложение/расширение браузера для авто сёрфинга интернета на буксах.

Некоторую логику для каждого букса ещё возможно продумать, но не могу определиться с языком для выполнения всех функций разработки.

Главные условия, какие будут проверки и авто действия:

1. проверка на авторизацию на буксе. Скорее всего методом открылась ли страница с личным профилем;
2. считывание страниц букса по разделам сёрфинг, видео и т.д.;
3. авто выполнение действий на странице. Например, нажать на заранее известный вариант ответа, перетащить ползунок и т.д.;
4. при успешном сёрфинге задания, например отображении начисленной награды после выполнения, закрывать страницу и переходить к следующему из пункта 2.

**Вопрос:**
Каким(и) языкам(и) программирования лучше и правильнее воспользоваться для данных действий?
И главное чтобы эту разработку в дальнейшем пустить в массы и она работала локально (с ip пользователя)

Comment: Золотое правило программиста -  стремиться писать код на том языке, которым он владеет. Желательно - владеет лучше, чем кодингом на других языках. Вот из этого и исходите.

Comment: @passant , "владеть" - слово растяжимое. Есть опыт в php, js, java, kotlin, 1C, C++, C#, python, vba. Все +- одинаково

Comment: @passant казалось бы, писать надо на том языке, которых подходит для задачи. Незнание - дело поправимое, а смена платформы такое себе.

Answer (score 1):

Буксы используют кучу защит от парсеров, ботов, эмуляторов и прочего.
Рекомендую изучить вопрос использования PhantomJS и скриптов к нему на JS или автоматизировать Ваши действия через программу Zennoposter (не бесплатная) он поможет решить все Ваши задачи, безграничная автоматизация, сам использую.

Comment: Поизучаю, спасибо

Comment: Если рассматривать требуемый функционал и Zennoposter, то тут и обычный макрос подойдет, подобных приложений уйма